# appharbor JustOneDB - "error":"Table creation needs a table name

Tags: database, json, appharbor

I plan on using JustOneDB on AppHarbor.
I tried the rest request below w/ curl and got

> {"error":"Table creation needs a table name"}

I'm  a noob when it comes to Curl and json.
Does anyone have experience w/ JustOneDB and creating a table.
What am I doing wrong?

TIA 
FxM :)

> "error":"Table creation needs a table name" justoneDB

I tried

```
curl -k -XPOST 'https://zn0lvkpdhdxb70l2ub4:iy59bj7rh0z6uurNA1lb3fiwuh@77.92.68.105:31415/justonedb/database/n10lvkpNA2uja/session/1946301333393883/table' -d '{
    "name"  : "tbl1",
    "column": "bob",
    "type"  : "string"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the JSON syntax you are using. The JSON string needs to be in the form

.../table {"name":"tbl1", "column":[ {"name":"bob","type":"string"} ]}

If you are unfamiliar with the syntax, it may help to cut/paste/edit from the examples from the JustOneDB REST reference guide. See here http://www.justonedb.com/appharbor